# Running karma-runner in SSL

Tags: ssl, ember.js, yeoman, qunit, karma-runner

I've built some integration test scripts for my Ember.js app within the Yeoman environment. It's a secure site that needs to connect to its remote API securely. Because of some mods I did in my Chrome instance to ignore security errors, my tests run just fine in Chrome.

But of course, I want to run my tests in multiple browsers, so when I try Firefox, I get CORS errors. So I tried to set up my karma.config.js as follows:

```
...
urlRoot: "/unit/",
proxies: {
  "/": "https://localhost.example.com/"
},
proxyValidateSSL: false,
hostname: 'localhost.example.com',
port: 9000, 
...
```

With this setup, I expected it to run the tests in SSL, yet when I start karma (whether manually or via grunt-cli), it loads non-securely. What am I missing?

Bryan

Comment: Why are you setting the hostname? I just tried your exact config (without the hostname) and it works fine - Karma proxies to localhost.example.com where is my SSL web server...

Comment: Thanks for your reply. When you say it works fine, in what sense? Does it load the URL being tested to be the https string that you set in the "proxies" field? When I comment out the hostname and set `singleRun: false` to observe what the browser does, it still pulls up a non-ssl URL. If I manually type the proxy URL, it doesn't do anything except give an error message "the connection was interrupted"